# servo increment in python

Tags: python, increment

```
servoMin = 500
servoMid = 1500
servoMax = 2500
servoTilt1 = 1500
servostep = 100

def servo1_up():
  servoTilt = servoTilt1 + servostep
  if servoTilt > servoMax:
   servoTilt = servoMax
  port.write("#15P%dT100\r\n" % servoTilt)
```

Hello,

Been writing some code to run a servo motor, but I can not seem to get it to
increment. Everything works fine but it will only increase by 100 (servostep) once when i push a key and i am trying to get it to move 100 every time I push a key. A point in the right direction would be great.

Thansk

Comment: Is that all the code you have which does this?

Comment: Instead of a command for tilting up (and presumably down) maybe just make a servo move function and send it positive or negative values?

Comment: I am using a torobot servo controller via serial and as far as i know it  only excepts commands like: port.write("#15P1500T100\r\n") wich i am trying to increment 100 everytime i push a button on my ps3 remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has fixed my issue

```
servoMin = 500
servoMid = 1500
servoMax = 2500
servoTilt = 1500
servostep = 100

def servo1_up():
  global servoTilt
  servoTilt += servostep
  if servoTilt > servoMax:
    servoTilt = servoMax
  port.write("#15P%dT100\r\n" % servoTilt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables, `servoTilt` and `servoTilt1`. The first one is local, the second is global. After you increment `servoTilt`, it's destroyed when it goes out of the scope and `servoTilt1` remains unchanged.

Solution: rename `servoTilt1` to `servoTilt`